# jquery delegate passing variable

Tags: jquery, delegates

I want to pass the object of being clicked into the handler. like this:

```
$selector.delegate('.test','click',func1( ?? ));

//this is a reusable function
function func1(obj){
    //do something with obj  .....
}
```

so in this case, I should pass $('.test') into the function. can anybody give me a hand here, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` inside `func1`. `this` will be the object on which the event occurred.

Comment: sorry, if I use $(this), I can not use the parameter obj...which is needed when this function gets called else where.

Comment: Then make a simple wrapper function to call `func1`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$selector.delegate('.test','click', function(e){
var obj =  this;
//obj will point to the element you clicked.
});
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. but sorry this is not what I am looking for, i am not using anomynous function.

Comment: You can still use the function you need. $selector.delegate('.test','click', func1); In func1 "this" will still point to the element you clicked.